# Err.description slow

Tags: excel, vba

The program takes 1-2 seconds on my pc

The slowness happens on the line 
`Debug.Print Err.Description`
If I replace it with Err.number, it takes 0s.

The problem consist, if I changed the code to display a `Type Mismatch` error message

I'm using Excel 2007, 64 bit Windows Server.

I have disabled all Add-in

I put the following code in a brand-new .xlsm file.

The problem is NOT about debug.print , if I change it into string comparsion, problem presists

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Public Sub Testing()
Err.Clear
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Problem

    Dim a As Double
    a = 10 / 0
Problem:
    Dim sOutput As String
    Dim lStart As Long, lEnd As Long


    lStart = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    lEnd = GetTickCount
    gsOutput = "Time requires : " & (lEnd - lStart) / 1000 & "s"
    Debug.Print gsOutput
End Sub
```

Any help would be nice.

**EDIT** 
Problem And Solution Found: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2683270

By the way, I do think this is not a localized question if the issue has been stated by Microsoft.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the time taken by your procedure to run the code ?

Comment: to run the line `Debug.Print Err.Description` alone takes me 2 seconds

Comment: @Larry, I just tested your code on multiple environments (2003, 2007, 2010, in 32 or 64bit) and cannot reproduce the problem. :-(

Comment: @PeterAlbert Thanks for helping out, I cannot reproduce this problem on other pc as well.

Comment: Do you want a work around or are wanting to understand the underlying issue? Also is this only the case for the error `13` or do all errors take this long to get the description?

Comment: Also what, if anything, happens to the ime if you set the `err.description` to a dummy `string` variable first then use it in `debug.print`?

Comment: @glh For all errors, tried, still the same slowness.   And yes, I know there's a workaround to use the Err.number but that would be a massive code change.

Comment: What if you try an alternate method for getting the time? And did you test a dummy variable?

Comment: @glh the problem really not in getting the time, if I removed the lines of getting time. The program still runs for 2s.. which should be 0s...

Comment: moderators, I don't think my case is "extraordinarily narrow situation" and just looking for someone had been in similar situation...

Comment: @PeterAlbert Hi, as you tried to help out, want to let you know the cause is found, please see my update in Question.

Comment: @glh Hi, as you tried to help out, want to let you know the cause is found, please see my update in Question.

Comment: @user2063626 Hi, as you tried to help out, want to let you know the cause is found, please see my update in Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem is because some registry value is missing on local computer.

As suggested [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2683270)

the winhelp.ini, which is used by Excel Process during error handling is missing ( You can check by using the [tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) suggested.)

Therefore, it's looking up from some other  %PATH% variable into network drive's C:\Windows\winhelp.ini.

the 1-2 Seconds are network delay.

The problem is solved by adding the registry mentioned.

HTH